# Display multiple values from comments table mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

here is mysql query

```
sqlCommand2 = "SELECT comment,bpid,cid from comments  where bpid='".$blogid."' ";
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCommand2) or die (mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$comm=$row["comment"];
}


<?php echo $comm;?>
```

here is my display in another page

but its is displaying only one value instead of all the values matching ?

Comment: use $com[]=$row['comment'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$comm is getting replaced with next value while looping.

Try :

```
$comm .= $row["comment"]. ' ';
```

Comment: its working ! but the comments list is not updating until rerfesh ?